# Can Automator's 'find finder items' ignore subfolders when searching?

Tags: macos, automator

I am using the Apple Automator to build a simple program that opens all the documents that belong to a project. All files are in the same folder and can be identified by the first characters of the file name; I am using the 'Find finder items'-action to find all these files, and then open them. However, there also files with similar names in a subfolder, that I do not want to open.

I would like the action to search only in the main folder, and to disregard the content of any subfolders. Is there a way to do this in Automator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes use the action "Ask for Folder Contents" (i hope its called like that on an English OS - I'm currently on a German one there it is called "Ordnerinhalt abfragen"), there you can say if you also wanna use subfolders or not.

I added a demo workflow for you.

[Demo Workflow](https://db.tt/9ewfUBfs)

Comment: Could you expand on how to use the aforementioned action to *search* for a file/folder?

Comment: it is just to select if you wana search the folder contents or also the subfolders to select the main folder just use the action you use already

Comment: @konqui There exists a 'Ask for Finder items'-action, but this gives a prompt from where I can choose the files. I would like to open all of them automatically.

Comment: there should be an action named "Selected Finder items" or if you like it really simple just drag'n'drop the Main Project Folder onto the right side of automator.

Comment: Doesn't work for me…I can check the 'Do this for all subfolders' box, but it does noet seem to make a difference.

Comment: if this doesn't work then your task may be to complex for Automator. then i recomend you to use the following Command inside a the Terminal. - cd /path/to/your/project/folder <press enter> - open <name of files e.g. project_x_*.*> <press enter> - if this also doesn't work Add a screenshot of the project folder and the files so we know about what we are talking.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake…works now. Now using 'Get specified Finder items' > 'Get folder contents' > 'Filter Finder items' > 'Open Finder items'.